# Limitations of Background agents and cross-app access in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background-process

Basically I'm working on a project where I need to:

1. Have a background service that can receive small packets of data from a paired bluetooth (BLE to be precise) device.
2. Based on the received data, perform various functions on built-in Windows apps (media player, camera, phone dialler etc.) like switch to the next/previous track, alter volume level, take a picture, call a number etc (basically control built-in apps).

Now there was an extensive hardware part to this project which I began working on assuming that Windows Phone would offer the same level of flexibility as Android and that the aforementioned tasks could be easily performed, but now that I searched around a bit and saw the  [constraints for Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx) I was dumbfounded to say the least, and by the looks of it the kind of functionality I'm looking for is completely unavailable in WP APIs. And while I couldn't find a definitive answer regarding the second task I wish to perform, I'm assuming the sandbox-style environment which WP apps run in will prevent that from happening as well.

Is there ANY way the above mentioned tasks can be performed with a Windows Phone 8.1 app or even something close?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: for various reasons Windows Phone is designed to provide ultimate control of system functions to the user. In general, all actions have to be user-initiated; even the background tasks have to be ok'd at some point. Reasons include battery life, stability, predictability.

A related policy is that no app may interfere with the operation of another. The only way apps can communicate is via launcher tasks or sharing protocols. Using these you can do things like [prompt the user to dial a number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394025%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Out of the tasks you list, the only one I can see being a feasible project is if you write your own camera app or music app that integrates with your Bluetooth device. It's either/or though, you won't be able to make a one-stop app.

Comment: Isn't it possible to create something like a system level app or driver that would enable this kind of functionality? Obviously that'd mean it can no longer be put on the app store but still.

Comment: No, there is no way to add a service or driver to the phone.